# When and where is a plugin called / fired / triggered?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, plugin

If I have a plugin for after a customer is saved eg

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
    <plugin name="Module_CustomerAfterSave" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomerAfterSave" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Is it possible to know when and where the save came from? Eg did it come from when the customer registered? Did it come from the customer updating their name or did it come from the admin updating the customer